# How to add height and width in a PHP script?

Tags: php

I have the following line. It works fine but I want to add height and width to the image. How?

```
echo "<td>" . "<img src='img/" .$row['Foto'] . "'>" . "</td>";
```

Comment: you can use inline (`style`) css or put an attribute `width` and `height` on `<img />` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `style` attribute :

```
echo "<td>" . "<img style = 'width:?;height:?' src = 'img/" .$row['Foto'] . "'>" . "</td>";
```

or `width` and `height` attributes :

```
echo "<td>" . "<img width = '?' height = '?' src = 'img/" .$row['Foto'] . "'>" . "</td>";
```